# Limit REST API access to angular app only in nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have a backend and frontend hosted on the same machine (digitalocean). Backend exposes REST API which is used by Angular frontend.

For security reasons I would like to restrict access to the API to allow only calls coming from the Angular app. Is this possible?

I would imagine something like this:

```
location /api {
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all; }
```

working, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your app and NGINX to only listen to `127.0.0.1` which makes your configuration a whole lot simpler. Just change your server block to change the `listen` directive.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:80; # or any other port you are using to listen.
  # Remove listen 80; listen 443; listen [::]:443; or listen [::]:80; 
  # All your other stuff...
}
```

Just that and you don't need all those allows and denies.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes connection refused error in angular app - is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Maybe your application is using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`. If that is the case you have two options: either listen to `localhost:80` on NGINX or change requests in the app to use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. If I were you I'd change in the app, because of the security: you avoid someone hijacking the `localhost` DNS